# creating a deb package to install extension

Tags: apt, package-management, deb

I want to create a deb package that will install [this](http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/marathi-spellchecker/releases/1.3/libre_office_4_autotext.oxt) and [that](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/marathi-dictionary/?src=userprofile) extensions.

I want to automate the steps of adding the extension to LibreOffice and Firefox. How do I create a package for this?

Comment: I think you will need a script, not a whole package, to achieve this, unless there's a reason you want to make this into a package?

Comment: I need a package because some other utilities will also be included # apt-get install ibus{,-m17n,,-gtk} im-config # apt-get install ttf-devanagari-fonts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating packages is relatively straight forward.  You essentially create a tarball, which could be unpacked at the root of your filesystem (the parallel directory structures), but in addition there is a debian folder, which contains scripts which can be run during the process.
I'm assuming you knew this, so I'm not sure exactly which bit of the process of creating a package, you're unclear on.

https://wiki.debian.org/HowToPackageForDebian

Will give you chapter and verse on creating the package

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Installing_extensions

Says putting .xpi files in a certain directory will cause firefox to install them on next startup

https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=804

Talks about using unopkg to install libreoffice packages from the command line.

If you want hired consultancy to do the grunt work for you, that's a different matter ;-)